# using Tkinter with condition in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use Tkinter in loop and not sure how to do that. I want to display an "Correct" message when certain condition is met using Tkinter. for ex if the value is <=20 then it should display message otherwise show " not correct". I am only able to create a code to display message but do not know how to use this message with the condition. Below is my code :

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

# This code is to hide the main tkinter window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Message Box
messagebox.showinfo(" Correct!!")
```

Comment: You should think about: 1) how do you get the *value* for comparison? 2) when do you perform the comparison?  SO is not a place for requesting code.  You should try it yourself first and ask question on the issue you come across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution will going to have an example inspired by your explanation about what you are trying to do.

Well your code would not do anything like you want to. So I am writing a code which will take a number input from a user. If the number is greater than 20 then it would display "Correct" else it would display "Incorrect".

---

**Here is the code I wrote:**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tkinter.Tk()

question = tkinter.Label(root, text="Enter any number")
question.place(x=5, y=5)
question_entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
question_entry.place(x=5, y=50)

def check():
    x = 20
    y = int(question_entry.get())
    if y >= x:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Check", message="Correct!")
    elif y < x:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Check", message="Incorrect!")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(title="Check", message="Some unexpected error occured!")

submit_button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Start", command=check)
submit_button.place(x=5, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

**Explanation:**

1. Using label to display "Enter any number"
2. I have used `Entry` widget to take input from the user. And to retrieve it I have used `int(question_entry.get())`. Also I have added `int()` to make the entry an integer as the default entry is `str`.
3. The function `check` is created so as to run the program when the button is pressed. I have used `command=check` attribute run the program when it is clicked.
4. `showinfo` is being used to send a message in a separate window. `showerror` is created in `else` condition just in case some error comes up. *(less likely to happen)*
5. I have removed the `root.withdraw()` statement as this program can be used multiple time. But just in case if you want to hide the window you can add `root.withdraw()` just above the line `x=20` and it would work just fine. (I tried is already)

---

It there is still something that I failed to explain, please feel free to ask in the comments. :)

Comment: thank you so much for explaining so thoroughly. It is working as expected. I can now understand better in terms of how to use Tkinter in a conditional loops.

Comment: My pleasure. Happy that I could explain. :)